# GIT: Removing file from version control but keeping old version on GitHub

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have a passwords file which I would like to keep on GitHub (without my passwords), so a person using my code can just type their own passwords in the file.  I would like to remove the file from version control when I type my passwords back in the file. How can I achieve this with git.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is having a `passwords.txt.dist` file with example data, and asking your users to copy and edit it.
The `passwords.txt` file should be ignored.

Comment: Ignored, and probably never committed to the repo (at least not to a public repo). +1.

Comment: If you ignore it you wouldn't be able to `add` it *easily*, you'd need to use the `--force` option.

Comment: Unfortunately, Git has no built-in way to stop people from doing stupid shit.

Comment: I'm talking about people who'd `add` a passwords file, which is ignored, using a `-f`. I think these are enough reasons to call this act *stupid*.

Comment: Adding passwords to a _public_ repo would be stupid - adding it to a private repo doesn't matter at all and may be required, not stupid. It's best not to assume what future readers, or other forks/repos created from the example in the question are going to do - otherwise assumptions come undone.